# using evosuite on windows

Tags: java, unit-testing, evosuite

Has anyone used evosuite tesing tool from the command line on windows OS? I know that the eclipse plugin is developed only for mac OS, but I am not sure about the .jar file. Can it be executed on windows? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, EvoSuite is only supported for Mac and Linux. It should also work for Windows. At least for Windows 7 it was working last time I tried.